# posts_per_page not returning correct number of posts

Tags: wp-query

```
$queryArgs = array(
'post_type' => 'recipe',
//'orderby' => 'menu_order',
'orderby' => 'date',
'order' => 'DESC',
'posts_per_page' => 10,
        //    'posts_per_page' => -1

);

query_posts($queryArgs);
```

I have my code above...it's not returning any posts.  If I set 'posts_per_page' to a higher number such as 80, then it returns posts.  Any idea why that is?

Comment: User [`wp_query()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) instead. [Learn more](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts)

Comment: Thanks @MayeenulIslam - $query = new WP_Query($queryArgs); did the trick